# How can I display this geojson data on the map

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I tried to test and display my geojson data.
But failed.

My geojson data:

````
var data= { "type": "MultiPolygon", 
"coordinates": [ [ [ 
[2875370.689553291071206, 4920425.686579301021993 ],
 [ 2875368.243538830429316, 4920426.618963065557182 ],
 [ 2875365.849673743359745, 4920427.678083536215127 ],
 [ 2875370.689553291071206, 4920425.686579301021993 ]
 ]]] }  ```


How can I display this geojson data on the map? 
regards
````

Answer (score 1):

You have a GeoJSON geometry object so you must use the OpenLayers `readGeometry()` then create a feature in a vector layer to display it.  This code presumes the geometry coordinates are in EPSG:3857 format

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View()
      });

      var data = { "type": "MultiPolygon", 
      "coordinates": [ [ [ 
      [2875370.689553291071206, 4920425.686579301021993 ],
       [ 2875368.243538830429316, 4920426.618963065557182 ],
       [ 2875365.849673743359745, 4920427.678083536215127 ],
       [ 2875370.689553291071206, 4920425.686579301021993 ]
       ]]] };

      var geometry = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readGeometry(data);

      map.addLayer(
        new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [new ol.Feature(geometry)]
          })
        })
      );

      map.getView().fit(geometry);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```